# Get DropdownList text in a Repeater Control ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the selected text on selected index change of the DropDownList. here is the Mock up.

```
   <pre> 
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# Eval("Teaenter code herem_Name")%></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><a href="http://localhost:4886/Payments/<%#Eval("Team_Payment")%>">View</a></td>
                            <td>       
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drlApplicationStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" CommandName="Update" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Team_ID")%>'OnSelectedIndexchanged="Selected_IndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem CssClass="text-center" Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem CssClass="text-center" Text="Active" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>                              
                                    <asp:ListItem CssClass="text-center" Text="Pending" Value="2 "></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
</pre>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void TeamList_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{

    DropDownList drlApplicationStatus = (DropDownList)source;

    if (drlApplicationStatus.SelectedIndex == 1 && e.CommandArgument !=null)
    {
        Teams.UpdateTeamStatus(int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()), "Active");
    }
    else if(drlApplicationStatus.SelectedIndex == 2 && e.CommandArgument != null)
    {
        Teams.UpdateTeamStatus(int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()), "Pending");
    }


}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: `drlApplicationStatus.SelectedItem.Text`

Comment: when the the selected item changes TeamList_ItemCommand method is not fired

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why the DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged doesn’t trigger the `ItemCommand` event. But you can do this:

```
    protected void repeater_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var drlApplicationStatus = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("drlApplicationStatus");
        drlApplicationStatus.SelectedIndexChanged += drlApplicationStatus_SelectedIndexChanged;

    }

    private void drlApplicationStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var drlApplicationStatus = (DropDownList)sender;
        Response.Write(drlApplicationStatus.SelectedValue);
        Response.Write(drlApplicationStatus.SelectedItem.Text);

    }
```